# Limit number of records in sub-form access

Tags: vba, ms-access

I created form and sub-form in access, one to many relationship. Form has room id and text-box no. of beds, in sub-form I want to add beds by bed id.

How to limit number of records in sub-form to be =< no. of beds?

Eg. if I have no. of beds value 4 I want to prevent user to add 5th bed in sub-form.I'm fairly new to access so detailed explanation would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how:

```
Public Sub SetFormAllowAdditions( _
  ByVal frm As Form, _
  ByVal lngRecordCountMax As Long)

' Limit count of records in (sub)form to that of lngRecordCountMax.
' 2004-10-06, Cactus Data ApS, CPH
'
' Call in (sub)form:
'
'   Private Sub LimitRecords()
'     Const lngRecordsMax As Long = 5
'     Call SetFormAllowAdditions(Me.Form, lngRecordsMax)
'   End Sub
'
'   Private Sub Form_AfterDelConfirm(Status As Integer)
'     Call LimitRecords
'   End Sub
'
'   Private Sub Form_AfterInsert()
'     Call LimitRecords
'   End Sub
'
'   Private Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
'     Call LimitRecords
'   End Sub

  Dim booAllowAdditions As Boolean

  With frm
    booAllowAdditions = (.RecordsetClone.RecordCount < lngRecordCountMax)
    If booAllowAdditions <> .AllowAdditions Then
      .AllowAdditions = booAllowAdditions
    End If
  End With

End Sub
```

That works for a constant maximum count of records. For a variable count, replace this line:

```
Const lngRecordsMax As Long = 5
```

with:

```
Dim lngRecordsMax As Long
lngRecordsMax = Nz(Me.Parent![no. of beds].Value, 1)
```

Also, modify the *Current* event of the main form like this:

```
Private Sub Form_Current()

    Forms(Me.Name)!NameOfYourSubformControl.Form.LimitRecords

End Sub
```

and change *LimitRecords* from a *Private Sub* to a *Public Function*:

```
Public Function LimitRecords()
```

Comment: I have problem after adding this code, if one record exist in sub-form where beds are everything works fine but if I add new record for form where rooms are I can't add any new record to it's sub-form because there are no text-boxes at all.

Comment: Yes, I think you need to adjust the minimum max. count from 0 to 1 (see edited answer). Also to "enable" the subform when creating a new record in the main form (see edit, last paragraph).

Comment: After changing value to 1 I got run-time error 2452 the expression you entered has invalid reference to parent property, pointing on line lngRecordsMax = Nzl.... When I changed lngRecordsMax back to 5 everything works as it should.

Comment: You must rename `Me.Parent![no. of beds]`to the actual name of the control (textbox/field) on the parent form holding the count of beds. If you set `lngRecordsMax` fixed to 5, you will always have 5 beds ...

Comment: I did rename [no. of beds] to name of my control and it works like I said but only if at least one record in sub-form already exist. I changed IngRecordsMax to 5 just to see if problem was in that part of code.

Comment: I see. I did a test, and it is not the AfterInsert event of the main form but the _Current_ event to be used. See modified answer please. This works here.

Comment: Can't tell. It is tested and works here, so I guess you have to double-check your code.

Comment: You are right I must have overlooked some part of old code, after recreating form and sub-form and adding code everything works as it should thank you for your help .

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.